# How do we do database connection string configuration in Spring Core or Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am from asp.net background and recently moved to Java and subsequently in Spring Core and then Spring Boot.
In asp.net we only had one file for all the configurations whether it is db connection string or any switch flag, everything related to config goes in web.config in asp.net.
How does it work in Spring Core and Spring Boot ?
What is the name of the file in this two cases ?

Answer (score 1):

A SpringApplication has bean properties (mainly setters) so you can use its Java API as you create the application to modify its behavior Or you can externalise the configuration using properties in `spring.main.*`. E.g. in `application.properties` or `application.yml`. Example of both these ways:

- Using bean setter properties for config. You can see the values being hardcoded:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

- Example of externalising with `application.properties`. Here these values are parsed and directly used for db connection:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html for more info.

Comment: when you say 'externalize' is there any other way as well ? Any 'interlization' way as well ?

Comment: @user2746466 yes, I have added examples of both of these

Comment: If I want to add more property files other than application.properties can I add that ? 
Say, I have to add 'flags.properties' then how do I add its reference of it in application.properties OR there is any other way ?

Comment: Yes, Checkout [spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles). You can create file called "application-flags.properties" and add it to the active profiles list and app will automatically pick it and apply overrides as required.